# Who is the intended user for apparmor?

Tags: apparmor

Ubuntu 18.04.2.

I am not a technically trained person, pretty much just a regular layman who uses Ubuntu.

I've been reading about apparmor, and struggling to understand its benefit.

I understand that once the profiles are set up, apparmor kind of "isolates" an application, limiting what it can do - and thereby limiting any damage it could cause.

A lot of the literature I've read has been praising the great benefit apparmor provides a system.

But, my system has only a few profiles in apparmor, so I am struggling to see how apparmor is doing much if any good for my system.  Yes, it is protecting my system from like 20 applications, but my system has FAR more applications that apparmor is doing nothing with.  So, I think, what is this great benefit that apparmor is providing my system?

In addition - For a "normal" user like me, who still cannot understand how to wisely create a profile for an application, what, if anything, did the creators of apparmor expect someone like me to do with apparmor?  I never do anything with it, because I don't know what I'm doing.

In summary, my two questions:

1. How does apparmor benefit my system when it has profiles for only a handful of applications; and,
2. What interaction with apparmor is a layman user expected to have?

Comment: AppArmor prevents some powerful, flexible processes from doing bad things if misused. A layman is usually expected to have no interaction with AppArmor at all...if the system is working properly. Laymen are certainly not expected to create AppArmor profiles. If you have a more specific problem, we can offer more specific advice.

Comment: @user535733 , No, I do not have a more specific question.  What you said is exactly what I needed to find out, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Per @user535733, apparmor isn't something a layman needs to be concerned with.  That is the confirmation I was needing.